# Rails setting empty strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here, I have built like 50 rails apps and now I can't tell if something changed recently or I'm having a lapse in judgment...

If I have my DB constraints set:

```
t.string  :ad_type,     null: false
t.string  :customer_id, null: false
```

And I have a form where they don't fill in values into the input fields, it used to raise an exception at the database level, I believe something like `PG::ViolatesNullConstraint` or something similar to that.

Now however, all my empty fields in `params` are empty strings and now no DB constraints are getting called.

```
@campaign = Campaign.create!(campaign_params)
```

WTF is going on? I'm using Rails 5.1.4

Comment: It's worth removing that comment and adding a self-answer. Plus, although personally I'm not offended by profanity it does rub people the wrong way, so might want to tone that down.

Comment: Actually that wasn't it. I removed the ajax submit entirely and it still submits empty strings to params.

Comment: Do you see anything in your `log/development.log` in the params? It's always a good idea to have that open at all times with `tail -f` to catch problems as they occur. You can see if the params are being missed, plus in your browser if they're ever submitted in the first place.

Comment: @tadman "plus in your browser if they're ever submitted" - the place to observe _this_ would be the browser console's network tab, or an http development proxy. In the server log you can only see how rails _interpreted_ what it received.

Comment: I currently have a binding.pry at the very top of the controller. `params` is setting every single empty input to `""`... is that normal rails behavior? I can't find any other projects but I know I did this in the past, and relied on the null constraint of the DB rather than model validations.

Comment: It's normal if that's what you're submitting over AJAX. `params` itself should be fairly raw, it's usually a faithful interpretation of what was received, so the next step is to check that you're actually posting the data correctly.

Comment: I'm using `form_with`, nothing out of the ordinary. I've removed ajax entirely from the situation. I'm using a simple `form_with model: @campaign`, and then `f.text_field :something`. Is the normal rails behavior to submit empty strings in this situation in the `params` has if an input isn't filled in? I'm not asking how to debug on my end (I know how to do that) im just wondering if this is the expected behavior and I had it wrong in my head for like 6 years

Comment: I tested in my browser `http://localhost:3000/?par1&par2=&par3=3` and in my controller (Rails 5.1.4) params are: Parameters: {"par1"=>nil, "par2"=>"", "par3"=>"3"}. However, if I send the request using a form, with 2 fields (and I don't fill one of them), the request is `http://localhost:3000/?par1=&par2=2` (so the controller receives par1 as an empty string, no nil). I don't remember if this happened in previous versions.

Comment: hmmm.... i must be crazy then. I would have bet my life on it being the other way. The only thing I can fathom is I've never relied on an null constraint for scalar values, and only things like foreign key constraints. For scalar values i probably also had a `presence: true` validation...